# Calling class in a class?

Tags: c#, class

I'm new.

my problem:

```
class Battle
{
    public void Fight(string charOne, string charTwo)
    {
        void CurrentHealth()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(charOne.name + "'s Health: " + 
                charOne.currentHealth + "/" + charOne.maxHealth + 
                "   |   " + charTwo.name + "'s Health: " + charTwo.currentHealth + 
                "/" + charTwo.maxHealth);
        }
    }
}
```

the ".name" and ".currentHealth" are not working.
charOne would be a class instance, and charTwo would be another class instance.

[UPDATE BELOW]

Below was the code that was originally working in the main program class, and I was trying to move it in to a class, where I could pass in some parameters to the class, so the Hero could fight other monsters in the future. This single time monster was "mosquito".
I just want to be able to replace a "mosquito" with a "wolf" class and maybe "hero2" instead of "hero". Hope this makes more sense.

```
                void CurrentHealth()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(hero.name + "'s Health: " + hero.currentHealth + "/" + hero.maxHealth + "   |   " + mosquito.name + "'s Health: " + mosquito.currentHealth + "/" + mosquito.maxHealth);
                }
                void Attack(int dmg)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(hero.name + " Dealt " + dmg + " damage to " + mosquito.name + ".");
                }


                while (mosquito.currentHealth > 0 && hero.currentHealth > 0)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    int damage = hero.AttackAction();
                    mosquito.currentHealth = mosquito.currentHealth - damage;
                    int newHealth = mosquito.currentHealth;
                    Attack(damage);
                    CurrentHealth();

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
                    Console.Read();

                }
                if (mosquito.currentHealth <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Right on! You are Victorious!!!");
                }
                else if (hero.currentHealth <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Oh no.. you are dead...");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You reached the end.");
                }
```

Comment: Umm... those are `string`s.

Comment: then make the parameters that class instead of `string`. String does not have those properties

Comment: i have a class "hero" and created using "new" keyword. I want to call: Battle.Fight(hero, monster)

Comment: @Edgaras Everything you need to solve the problem is already in the comments.

Comment: public void Fight(string charOne, string charTwo) should be: public void Fight(Hero charOne, Hero charTwo)

Comment: @Edgaras then make fight like so: `public void Fight(Hero charOne, Monster charTwo)` you need to have a monster class too btw. If it is `Hero` vs `Hero` then `charTwo` will be a `Hero` too

Comment: I didnt know it could be "class" not a "string". I just did that, but the problem is the same. I want to be able to throw in the classes myself. if the Hero will fight a dog, or a wolf.

Comment: And nobody noticed the function within a function?

Comment: @Edgaras If you want the "monster class" to be interchangeable (pass a hero class and any monster class) make a "monster `interface`"

Comment: Ah yes, if his class is "hero" rather then "Hero" it should indeed be what @MongZhu instead. Though looking at the fact that we are programming in C# I would recommend to start Class names with a Capital letter.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer That's actually possible in C# 7

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer wow, it's like an optical illusion of malformed code!

Comment: @Edgaras It sounds like you're looking for ways to get around having proper OOP, I recommend you try to read more about the language before continuing.

Comment: what type is `monster` ?

Comment: Sorry all, really trying to understand this. Without parameters this was working perfectly when it was in the main program class. Since I wanted to move it away from the main program. ALL I WANT, is to be able to pass in any instances of a class in to this class method and let them two "fight". unfortunately with all the comments read, I could not get this to work. I guess I do need to read up more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Fight(MyCharacterClass charOne, MyCharacterClass charTwo)
```

Try it like this, of course change your own class with  **MyCharacterClass**

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :). It would be if you could mark it as answer then.

Comment: Sorry, first timer here.. I was looking for it, didn't realise its a greyed out tick. Easy to miss.